# awk for separating word by underscores

Tags: regex, awk, underscore.js

I am really terrible at using awk, but I know it's pretty useful for strain operations.

I have a file of the form:

```
JohnSmith_name    3.4     
KellySears_name   5.7
RonaldBay_name    1.2     
RayShendor_name   2.8
```

I want to read the file and basically strip the _name tag from the real name and print the line. How can I do that using awk??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` more easily than `awk` in this case, I think:

```sh
$ sed s/_name// file
JohnSmith    3.4     
KellySears   5.7
RonaldBay    1.2     
RayShendor   2.8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 awk '{sub("_name",""); print}'
```

(however as the Carl Norum said - sed may be better)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
awk -F "_name" '{ print $1.$2 }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Good ol' `bash` way:

```
$ while read col1 col2; do echo -e "${col1%_*}\t$col2"; done < file
JohnSmith   3.4
KellySears  5.7
RonaldBay   1.2
RayShendor  2.8
```